# Asterisk PBX call recording

Tags: asterisk, pbx

Asterisk version 1.8.28.2
FreePBX version 2.11.0.37

When an outbound call is transferred , the recordings is saved in two files ( one before call transfer ,and one after transfer)

Can this combined in single file ?

Comment: Do you want Asterisk to combine it, or are you asking about how to do it after Asterisk has saved the two files ?

Comment: I want asterisk to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in freepbx.

You can do in custom dialplan like this

```
[incoming]
exten => _X.,1,Mixmonitor(${EXTEN}-${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},GMT+8,%C%y%m%d%H%M)}.wav)
exten => _X.,2,Dial(LOCAL/${EXTEN}@from-pstn/n)
```

but you will have issues with cdrs and not able see it in freepbx web.

Other option is create script which will merge files, but that is complex.

Answer (score 0):

Search about using the AUDIOHOOK_INHERIT with the MixMonitor dialplan application.  You'll need to manually edit extensions.conf, though, which means updates to the dialplan via FreePBX will stop these changes.